# Regex. Найти предложения начинающиеся на слово и заканчивающееся на ; и удалить в этом предложении перенос строки

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть текстовый файл, в котором нужно найти предложения, начинающиеся на слово SSIGN и заканчивающееся на ; разорванные переносом строки и удалить этот перенос.

```
some text
some text
SSIGN (EE_10.T.E.6.OT + 
EE_9.T.E.7.OT) * 
FLASH + 
 TO LED.3;
some text
some text
```

Вроде вот это работает `SSIGN[()\w\s.+*]+;` но это только находится строка, а как в ней теперь удалить переносы \r\n.

И еще нужно найти строки начинающиеся с пробела.

Comment: Давайте по очереди. Чтобы найти "предложение", вам нужен `(?sm)^SSIGN.*?;\r?$`, да? Всё, начиная от начала строки, до ближайшего `;` в конце строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно использовать `Regex.Replace()` с лямбдой, которая будет удалять [не]нужные символы из найденных групп.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"SSIGN[()\w\s.+*]+;");
var result = regex.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(match =>
{
    return match.Value.Replace("\r\n", "");
}));
```

Comment: Сработало! Премного благодарен!